# Using \multicolumn in an array in RMarkdown to HTML in RStudio

Tags: knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I put the following code into an RMarkdown file in RStudio.

```
Here are the reading scores for both the treatment group and the control group.
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{Treatment group}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{Treatment group}}\\\hline
24 & 56 & 42 & 46
\end{array}$$
```

When I compile using knitHTML, I get the following image.

[image]

Can someone share something that works?

Thanks.

David.

Answer (score 1):

R Markdown is [using](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/using_markdown_equations) Mathjax to render LaTeX equations, that you can try [here](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/). You will see that it's rendered with JS just like your output, so it's not an R or markdown issue.

As a matter of fact your example did not even work here in a simple LaTeX article, so I tried instead:

```
$$
\begin{array}{c c c c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Treatment group} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Treatment group} \\\hline
24 & 56 & 42 & 46
\end{array}
$$
```

But it has the same issues with Mathjax, as it's not supported based on a [thread started in 2011](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/YdA4JlwbZ28).

I would rather create a HTML table instead of trying to transform a LaTeX array into that, see e.g.: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp